# Set length for input type

Tags: javascript, html

I try to do a simple JavaScript function to set length for type "text" for the input tag. I want it perform match found whenever the text reach 6 character. I do this code below, the problem is before enter 6 letters also it says match found.

```js
function clean(e) {
  var t = document.getElementById(e);
  var regex = /[^a-z _ ].{6,}/gi;
  if (t.value.search(regex) > -1) {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "  NO match found";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "  match found";
  }
  t.value = t.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

```html
<input id="ta" name="ta" onkeyup="clean('ta')" onkeydown="clean('ta')" type="text" />
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: This is not Java. Please make an effort to learn the name of the language you're attempting to write code in.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing javascript function when html provides `maxlength` attribute to set the maximum length?

Simply use:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="6">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clean(e) {
      var t = document.getElementById(e);
      var regex = /[a-z].{6}/;
      if (t.value.search(regex) < 0) {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "  NO match found";
      } else {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "  match found";
      }
      t.value = t.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking how to trigger an action the moment the input string hits 6 characters. The answer you have given only sets the maximum string length, but it doesn't do anything otherwise. The subject line should actually be revised...